# Using DSolve to solve a system of two vector valued equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have a system of ODE that is most easily posed in the form
$$ \frac{d \mathbf{x}}{dt} = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}), 
\frac{d \mathbf{y}}{dt} = \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) \text{ where } \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^3.
$$
Looking at the examples in the documentation, I know how to input a system of $2$ scalar equations

```
DSolve[{x'[t]==y[t],y'[t]==-x[t]},{x,y},t]
```

or a single vector-valued equation

```
DSolve[y'[t] == {{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . y[t], y ∈ Vectors[2], t]
```

I have tried a few variations on the following in order to solve a system two vector-valued ODE, but with no luck.

```
DSolve[{y'[t] == {{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . x[t], x'[t] == {{2, 0}, {0, 3}} . y[t]}, 
{x, y} ∈ Vectors[2], t]
```

It would be trivial to reformulate the above example in terms of a single variable in $\mathbb{R}^4$, but the problem I want to solve eventually would be much more difficult to do this with, and I'd like to keep my Mathematica as close as I can to what I do with pencil and paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the desire to keep notation compact by working with vector valued variables but for the purpose of `DSolve` it seems one has to switch to a component-wise implementation. Looking at the limited examples for `DSolve` using `∈ Vectors[...]` the functionality seems to be limited at best. I think part of the problem is that `Part` will not work properly/as expected: `x[t][[1]]` evaluates to `t` while `x[t][[2]]` returns an error, since `Part` does not really like to remain unevaluated. This is why all the examples involving `∈ Vectors[...]` do not include componentwise/-specific operations.

I would recommend switching to a componentwise formulation:

```
xv[t_:t]:=Array[Subscript[x,#][t]&,2]
yv[t_:t]:=Array[Subscript[y,#][t]&,2]

DSolveVector[eqs_,f_List,t_,opts___]:=DSolve[eqs/.Equal[a_List,b_List]:>Sequence@@MapThread[Equal,{a,b}],Flatten@f,t,opts]
DSolveVector[eqs_,f_,t_,opts___]:=DSolveVector[eqs,{f},t,opts]

{xv'[t]=={c,d},yv'[t]=={c,d},xv[0]=={1,2},yv[0]=={2,3}}
DSolveVector[%,{xv[t],yv[t]},t]
{x[t]->xv[t],y[t]->yv[t]}/.#&/@%
```

> [image: Result]

Defining and working with `xv` and `yv` still allows for a reasonably compact notation. This also allows an implementation of $F$ and $G$ (from the question) involving componentwise operations: *e.g.* `F[x_,y_]:={x[[1]],y[[2]]}` works properly with `F[xv[t],yv[t]]` resulting in `{x_1[t],y_2[t]}`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. As always, this is part of a larger computation, so while this answer is helpful, I still need to see how to adapt it to my overall goal.